# How to get past level 4?

Tags: teleglitch

I've been playing the old teleglitch for a while and easily got to level 5 and as best level 8.

Since Die More I've yet to finish level 4. So far I've put about 8 hours into die more.

What kills me is the groups of red guards (the ones with guns).

How to manage those?

I've tried hiding and sneaking a kill and then move to repeat but so far it hasn't worked out.

Edit: I have little trouble getting to level 4.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me to play Die More Edition! I've just finished level four. Those guards were brutal, but I've stocked enough medkits from previous levels to recover after a nasty encounter with three roamers and a swarm of zombies. I don't think there's any special trick there: just be careful and carry a bigger gun. Range and corners help.

Comment: And level five did me in. I managed to get a closer look at the red guards, though! They seem to hit a lot harder than in original Teleglitch, but they take a little while to take aim. So when you see them raise their guns, duck!

Comment: @Pvt.Grichmann Yes, I managed to kill them on lvl4 aswell by using a cangun on them. Then got done in by them on lvl5 same as you.
Also, if the red guards are like this I positively dread the scientists. Those were the hardest in the old game and if they are boosted as much as the red guards... Yeah.

Comment: Have fun with the walkers when you get there!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, as I've now managed to get to level 9 I think I can advice on the guards.

1. Make sure to sneak around a corner or behind a door and wait for them to come to you.
2. Use a shotgun or similar weapon that does a lot of damage upfront. The AGL kills them in one grenade but they can still fire when tagged with a grenade.
3. Profit

As for the scientists (which are basically upgraded guards) the same tactics apply apart from the fact that they take more punishment and deal more damage.

Still one AGL grenade kills them, otherwise good weapons include the teslacoil.